# Сжать изображение на winapi

Tags: c, windows, winapi, jpeg

Всем привет. Я делаю скриншот экрана с помощью этого кода:

```
BOOL WINAPI SaveBitmap(WCHAR *wPath)
{
BITMAPFILEHEADER bfHeader;
BITMAPINFOHEADER biHeader;
BITMAPINFO bInfo;
HGDIOBJ hTempBitmap;
HBITMAP hBitmap;
BITMAP bAllDesktops;
HDC hDC, hMemDC;
LONG lWidth, lHeight;
BYTE *bBits = NULL;
HANDLE hHeap = GetProcessHeap();
DWORD cbBits, dwWritten = 0;
HANDLE hFile;
INT x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN);
INT y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN);

ZeroMemory(&bfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER));
ZeroMemory(&biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
ZeroMemory(&bInfo, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
ZeroMemory(&bAllDesktops, sizeof(BITMAP));

hDC = GetDC(NULL);
hTempBitmap = GetCurrentObject(hDC, OBJ_BITMAP);
GetObjectW(hTempBitmap, sizeof(BITMAP), &bAllDesktops);

lWidth = bAllDesktops.bmWidth;
lHeight = bAllDesktops.bmHeight;

DeleteObject(hTempBitmap);

bfHeader.bfType = (WORD)('B' | ('M' << 8));
bfHeader.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
biHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
biHeader.biBitCount = 24;
biHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
biHeader.biPlanes = 1;
biHeader.biWidth = lWidth;
biHeader.biHeight = lHeight;

bInfo.bmiHeader = biHeader;

cbBits = (((24 * lWidth + 31)&~31) / 8) * lHeight;

hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(hDC, &bInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, (VOID **)&bBits, NULL, 0);
SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, lWidth, lHeight, hDC, x, y, SRCCOPY);


hFile = CreateFileW(wPath, GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, &bfHeader, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, &biHeader, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), &dwWritten, NULL);
WriteFile(hFile, bBits, cbBits, &dwWritten, NULL);

CloseHandle(hFile);

DeleteDC(hMemDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);

return TRUE;
}
```

Но файл получается слишком большим, около 2300кб. Есть ли какой нибудь способ сжать его в несколько раз средствами winapi?

Comment: а вы не думали насчет средств стандартных библиотек а не апи ОС?) Например сконвертировать bmp в png(без потери качества) или jpeg(с потерей качества).

Comment: ам, ну вообще я стараюсь писать без crt, но допустим, как мне это сделать?

Comment: "вообще я стараюсь писать без crt" - так и хочется сказать цитатой: "Я не скажу, что это подвиг. Но что то героическое в этом есть"

Comment: Первое что показал запрос в гугле, https://lodev.org/lodepng/ , дальше ищите под ваши требования алгоритм и реализуйте

Comment: таки хочется обойтись средствами системы)

Comment: А чем не устраивает использование [GDI+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-using-image-encoders-and-decoders-use)?

Comment: Кто сказал, что не устраивает) Сейчас посмотрим, вроде подходит, спасибо